# invalid argument in mmap

Tags: c, mmap, invalid-argument

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* fprintf */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* exit */
#include <string.h>     /* memset */
#include <sys/mman.h>       /* mmap */
#include <sys/types.h>      /* pthread types */
#include <sys/stat.h>       /* fchmod */
#include <pthread.h>        /* thread primitives */
#include <fcntl.h>      /* open */
#include <unistd.h>     /* ftruncate */
#include <errno.h>      /* errno */

#define LIB_ADDR   0xaabbccdd   /* memorable random address */

#define UNMAP_FILE "unmapfile"
#define PAGE_SIZE 1024
#define DIE(msg)                \
    printf("-----\nDIE:%s\n-----\n", msg)

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int err;
  int unmap_fd;

  unmap_fd = open(UNMAP_FILE, O_RDWR | O_CREAT);
  if (unmap_fd < 0) DIE("open of unmap file failed");

  err = ftruncate(unmap_fd, PAGE_SIZE);
  if (err) DIE("ftruncate unmap file to page size failed");

  err = mmap((void *)LIB_ADDR + PAGE_SIZE, PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_FIXED, unmap_fd, 0);
  if (err = MAP_FAILED) DIE("mmap of to-be-unmapped page failed");

  return 0;
}
```

What I am doing is quite simple. I just want to `mmap` a file onto a fixed address, but I get the error `mmap of to-be-unmapped page failed`. I have checked everything but still have no idea.

Comment: `err = MAP_FAILED` should be `err == MAP_FAILED`?

Comment: `=` is use to assign value from right to left. use `==` for comparison. `if (err == MAP_FAILED)`

Comment: Pro tip: enabling compiler warnings (e.g. `gcc -Wall ...`) would have made this error immediately apparent - always compile with warnings enabled, and don't ignore any such warnings !

Comment: @Himanshu Thanks for your reply. I have modified all the changes as suggest, but the same problem still remains there.

Comment: @immibis Thanks for your reply. I have modified all the changes as suggest, but the same problem still remains there.

Comment: Is `0xaabbccdd` a multiple of the page size? Is it not mapped and not reserved for the kernel? (If you don't know any of those things, why are you trying to map at a fixed address instead of letting mmap pick one for you?)

Comment: @immibis Thanks for your reply. The reason I set it to `MAP_FIXED` is that I want to manually `msync` that `mmap` page later.

Comment: @HuangJie Why do you need to use MAP_FIXED to use msync?

Comment: @immibis Later, I wrote it this way: `msync((void *) (LIB_ADDR + PAGE_SIZE), PAGE_SIZE, MS_SYNC);` I just want to `msync` at that exact page. So do you have any recommendations for the code in order to achieve the goal? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @HuangJie Let mmap pick an address for you. Read the man page to find out how to do that

Answer (score 2):

This

```
  if (err = MAP_FAILED) DIE("mmap of to-be-unmapped page failed");
```

should be

```
  if (err == MAP_FAILED) DIE("mmap of to-be-unmapped page failed"); 
//Notice the ==
```

You are just assigning here and it makes the condition true.

`mmap(2)` returns a `void*`. So type of `err` is also wrong. Declare a new void pointer and use it:

```
void *mptr;
....
....

 mptr = mmap((void *)LIB_ADDR + PAGE_SIZE, PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_FIXED, unmap_fd, 0);
 if (mptr == MAP_FAILED) DIE("mmap of to-be-unmapped page failed");
```

Comment: Thanks for your notice. I have modified all the changes as you suggested. But the same problem still remains there.

Comment: Inspect the `errno` after `ftruncate` and `mmap` calls and see what it says.

Comment: I changed it to `if (mptr == MAP_FAILED) {perror("mmap"); fprintf(stderr, "Whoops");}` so that I can check. And it prints `mmap: invalid argumnet`.

Comment: That's `EINVAL`. So mmap doesn't like one of the values passed. I suspect it's MAP_FIXED. MAP_FIXED requires the addr is a multiple of the page size (read [mmap manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)). But the addr you use (0xaabbccdd) is not a multiple of page size you use (1024).